# Figure with a caption and formulas

Tags: floats, chemformula

I need to place a figure on the left, and formulas on the right, but I also need to add a caption to the figure. I have a mistake if I add `\caption`, and wrong location if I add `\begin{figure}`. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\parindent0em
\begin{multicols}{2}[\columnsep2em]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
%\caption{The caption}
\label{image12}
\columnbreak
\begin{equation}
X = A - y
B = B + N 
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use `\captionof{figure}{The caption}` if you load either `\capt-of` or `caption`.

Comment: B.t.w., why not simply two  minipages side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a caption outside a `figure` environment, you can use `\captionof{figure}{...}` from the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}


\parindent0em
\begin{multicols}{2}[\columnsep2em]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{The caption}
\label{image12}
\columnbreak
\begin{equation}
X = A - y
B = B + N 
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @L.Bond You're welcome! Personally I would follow Bernards suggestion and simply use two minipages

Comment: I haven't think about it, I will try it as well.